# Spring Batch, JdbcExecutionContextDao java.util.Map$Entry deserializer issue, xstream 1.4.1

Tags: java, maven-2, spring-batch, xstream, jettison

I have a problem using Spring Batch 2.1.9:
when i use *jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId)*, i find a problem when DAO has to deserialize a string like:

```
{"map":[{"entry":{"string":"parsedComparingDate","date":"2014-03-08 23:00:00.0 UTC"}}]}
```

from the **BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT** table, using method `JdbcJobExecutionDao.getJobExecution()`.

I know that spring batch uses xstream 1.3, but in my Pom, i have:

- **spring-batch 2.1.9**;
- **xstream 1.4.1** (inherited from smooks);
- **jettison 1.3.3** (inherited from cxf);

Also, i read that xstream 1.3 does not work fine with jettison 1.3.3, but using xstream 1.3 (excluding xstream 1.4.1 from pom) the job works correctly, while, using xstream 1.4.1 or major, i find the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: java.util.Map$Entry
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_23]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.Sun14ReflectionProvider.newInstance(Sun14ReflectionProvider.java:75) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.instantiateNewInstance(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:424) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:229) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.putCurrentEntryIntoMap(MapConverter.java:85) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:77) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:71) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.unmarshal(MapConverter.java:66) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1035) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1019) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:895) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:886) [xstream-1.4.1.jar:]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:48) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:222) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:215) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:649) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:714) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:202) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:209) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:106) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
```

1) i have seen the code, can i configure the **XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer** in order to set *reflectionProvider = null* (in this way, it will not uses the Provider) ?

2) there are other solutions to fix my problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible for me to change xstream version and jettison version because they imported by other components (like smooks).

A possible solution could be to create two different **JBoss modules** and to use them togheter.

So, i find another solution: use *spring-batch 2.2.0.RELEASE*, and use `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.DefaultExecutionContextSerializer` as serializer instead of *XStream*.

Below the configuration:

```
<bean id="batchDefaultSerializer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.DefaultExecutionContextSerializer" />

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="batchTransactionManager" />
    <property name="lobHandler" ref="defaultLobHandler" />
    <property name="serializer" ref="batchDefaultSerializer" />
</bean>       

<bean id="jobExplorer"      
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="serializer" ref="batchDefaultSerializer" />
</bean>
```

I tested it and it works fine, so, i think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the incompatibility of Jettison 1.2+ with XStream, upgrading XStream will cause Spring Batch to break.  This is something that was recently identified but has not been addressed yet.  The solution for your issue is to use Jettison 1.2 and XStream 1.4.7

Comment: It's impossible for me to change xstream version and jettison version because they imported by other components (like smooks).

Comment: Isn't Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer the best way to go?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0 with Spring Batch 3.0.7 and ran into this problem with a microservice that is using the Netflix OSS components b/c they use XStreams 1.4.2.

I'm also using Java configuration instead of XML. Here's what I came up with to solve the issue:
In a @Configuration class:

```
   @Bean
   public ExecutionContextSerializer serializer()
   {
      return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public JobRepository jobRepository( DataSource dataSource, 
                                       PlatformTransactionManager txManager ) throws Exception
   {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean fac = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        fac.setDataSource( dataSource );
        fac.setTransactionManager( txManager );
        fac.setSerializer( serializer() );
        fac.afterPropertiesSet();
        return fac.getObject();
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public JobExplorer jobExplorer( DataSource dataSource ) throws Exception
   {
      JobExplorerFactoryBean fac = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
      fac.setDataSource( dataSource );
      fac.setSerializer( serializer() );
      fac.afterPropertiesSet();
      return fac.getObject();
   }
```

I'm using Postgres as a backing store, so the DefaultExecutionContextSerializer didn't work as it tried to serialize binary instead of UTF-8 (JSON).